# Automount ext4 partition with user permission/ownership (fstab?)

Tags: partitioning, permissions, fstab, automount, ext4

1. I just installed Lubuntu 12.10 "Quantal Quetzal" on my Acer Aspire One D257, creating the partitions:

   ```
   $ df -h
   Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   /dev/sda5        15G  2.1G   12G  15% /
   ...
   /dev/sda1      1008M   62M  896M   7% /boot
    /dev/sda6        15G  180M   14G   2% /home
   /dev/sda4       195G  188M  185G   1% /media/data
   ```

   (or see partitions.png:)

   [image: partitions.png]

   (I know boot partitions were useful for old bios, but now they are also useful for encryption, LVM... (though differerent from a dedicated GRUB partition !))
2. I renamed the "data" partition (=`sda4`) flag/name (using utility Disks).
3. I have been trying for hours now to find a solution to:

   > **How to get my data partition (not my home partition!) to auto-mount at boot time somewhere (if possible in /media/data) with me (user =
   >   christophe) as owner and the permissions as rwxrwxr-x (=user:rwx,
   >   group:rwx, other:r-x)?**
4. My problems are that every time I reboot:

   - `/media/data` is back under root ownership
   - `/media/data` is back under rwxr-xr-x permissions
   - `/media/data` *content* is back as just lost+found *(!!!)*
   - frequently, when trying options in `/etc/fstab`, I had *"an error occurred while mounting /media/data"* at boot time.
5. I tried mostly to edit my `/etc/fstab` file. Now it is:

   ```
   $ cat /etc/fstab
   # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
   #
   # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
   # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
   # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
   #
   # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
   # / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
   UUID=8325697c-2c27-49dd-99f8-2a1a3e1467be /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
   # /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
   UUID=3ba24cc6-e38b-48d9-b526-68358783d980 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
   # /home was on /dev/sda6 during installation
   UUID=1ef16ece-0965-4611-a2e5-dd687f4ee5ff /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
   # /media/data was on /dev/sda4 during installation
   # UUID=0598f54b-dcf8-4508-97de-94d9f2c5e2a8 /media/data   ext4    defaults        0       2
   UUID=0598f54b-dcf8-4508-97de-94d9f2c5e2a8 /media/data     ext4    rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,user,async,errors=remount-ro,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000        0       2
   # swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
   UUID=04f73159-479d-4a4b-a78c-37a406909225 none            swap    sw              0       0
   ```
6. In a way, I'd like my data partition to automount like my home partition.
7. **I do not want a solution where I would have to chmod or chown or do something *every time* I (re)boot!**

Thanks.

Comment: This appears different from the similar question flagged. First, it is a specific sub-case of the general question addressed in the linked question. Second, it is more easily findable via search by someone with a more limited knowledge of Linux/Ubuntu, making it more valuable, in that it addresses the particular use case likely to need this answer, instead of the actual method to be accomplished.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**I think the key was to mount in either `/mnt/data` or `/media/username/data`** (username = christophe in my case) !!! I don't know why it works, but it seems to do so...

Definition of **"works"** :

1. Get my data partition to auto-mount at boot time in `location` (`media/christophe/data` or `/mnt/data`) with `user_name` (= me = christophe) as owner. *(Note: I have not dealt yet with the permissions (as rwxr--r-- (= user:rwx, group:r--, other:r--))).*
2. Every time I reboot:

   - the owner of `location` is not root, but `user_name` (me, christophe)
   - the content of `location` content is not wiped-out, but is persistent
   - there is no *"an error occurred while mounting ..."* at boot time.
   - the solution is a one-time solution, not every-time

Solutions:

1. **Solution in `/mnt/`**.

   - Edit `/etc/fstab` (for example `$ sudo nano /etc/fstab`) and add the line:

     ```
     UUID=your_uuid_value  /mnt/data       ext4    defaults        0       2
     ```
   - Double check before rebooting:

     ```
     $ ls -l /mnt/
     total 0
     ```
   - Reboot
   - Double check after rebooting:

     ```
     $ ls -l /mnt/
     total 4
     drwxr--r-- 2 christophe christophe 4096 Dec 26 04:02 data
     $ ls -l /mnt/data/
     total 4
     -rw-rw-r-- 1 christophe christophe 6 Dec 26 04:07 1.txt
     ```
   - Conclusion: It does work BUT it does not appear as a media in file manager (nautilus, PCManFM, ...) [see file_manager.png]
2. **Solution in `/media/username`**:

   - In terminal:

     ```
     $ sudo mkdir -p /media/username/
     ```

     Or, in my case:

     ```
     $ sudo mkdir -p /media/christophe/
     ```
   - Double check before rebooting:

     ```
     $ ls -l /media/
     total 4
     drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Dec 26 04:25 christophe
     $ ls -l /media/christophe/
     total 0
     ```
   - Edit `/etc/fstab` (for example `$ sudo nano /etc/fstab`) and add the line:

     ```
     UUID=your_uuid_value  /media/christophe/data       ext4    defaults        0       2
     ```
   - Reboot
   - Double check after rebooting:

     ```
     $ ls -l /media/
     total 4
     drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Dec 26 04:25 christophe
     $ ls -l /media/christophe/
     total 4
     drwxr--r-- 2 christophe christophe 4096 Dec 26 04:31 data
     $ ls -l /media/christophe/data/
     total 4
     -rw-rw-r-- 1 christophe christophe 6 Dec 26 04:37 2.txt
     ```
   - Conclusion: It does work AND it does indeed appear as a media in file manager (nautilus, PCManFM, ...) [see file_manager.png][image: file_manager.png]

Please feel free to add any comments, problems, or suggestions to this thread. I lost so many hours in that, I hope it will help others. In particular, I'd be curious to know *why* it works...

Cheers.

Comment: I tried the 2nd solution (`/media/paolo/SDISO` in my case) **but** I had to do `chown paolo:paolo /media/paolo/SDISO` while mounted, and one time only, as *psusi* said. Otherwise, after reboot and automount, I got my mountpoint owned by root, and ro for paolo. I hope this helps!

Comment: It doesn't have to be /media/user, any location will be ok, for example, mount it in /media/usbkey, then `sudo chown user:user /media/usbkey`, after that when you remount it, it will be owned by user.

Answer (score 23):

There are no uid options for ext[234].  If you want to change the permissions of the files, you have to use `chown/chmod`.

```
sudo chown -R myname.myname /media/data/
```

Comment: See point 7 in question. That a solution that is **not** adapted to my needs.

Comment: @Christophe, the effect is permanent, not something you have to do repeatedly.

Comment: I don't know why, but this wasn't/isn't the case for me, as I said in the question. Hopefully it is that simple for most people, but sadly it wasn't...

Comment: @Christophe, you need to do it while the partition is mounted, not before.