# shared swap problem with Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 dual boot

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, swap, cryptswap

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside an existing Ubuntu 16.04 installation where they share swap space. I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377516/sharing-of-swap-partiton-between-linux-systems) that this is possible, however, when I boot up Ubuntu 16.04, I get
`Enter passphrase for disk cryptswap1 on none!`

After I give my passphrase and log in, swap seems to work, I checked `cat /proc/meminfo` and it shows `SwapTotal: 12182524 kB`.

and `cat /etc/fstab` shows:
`# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation`
`#UUID=de7f23a9-64f0-451f-a42a-2d4cb921d804 none swap sw 0 0`
`/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0`

If it matters, the shutdown and restart buttons don't work anymore.

Thanks!